# JAVA: how would I make an if statement for if there is a remainder to print a line of code?

Tags: java, if-statement, modulo

The problem is down at the bottom. I made a single line comment to indicate the area. I think I need to add some kind of conditional in there? No clue. Thank you for your time.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class how {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int gumBalls;
    int kids;
    int gpk;

    System.out.println("How many gum balls? How many kids?");

    gumBalls = myScanner.nextInt();
    kids = myScanner.nextInt();

    gpk = gumBalls / kids;

    System.out.print("each person gets ");
    System.out.print(gpk);
    System.out.print(" gumballs");


    //this is where I am stuck  
    if (gpk % > 1) {
        System.out.println("Better throw those extras away..");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what you want to do with if condition?

Comment: Don't understand the down votes. Sometimes the SO community is so negative. I think that this question is a fine question, and one that should be asked on SO.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (gumBalls % kids  != 0) {
    System.out.println("Better throw those extras away..");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

% is an expression that expresses the remains of a division.

```
Lets say 20 / 4.
```

That makes 5 and there is no remains left after the division.

However if we decide to take a look at

```
23/4
```

In this case we would be able to get a full group of 4, 5 times and then there would be 3 left.

The sentence i just wrote here could be described as

```
23%4 = 3;
```

With that said the problem you faced was that you was not actually giving an ifstatement to be checked. If-Statements demands for them to be a solution where they can return either true or false and

```
24% is not able to return a boolean since it's not really checking anything at all.
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Sorry but no... I know that % is used to get a remainder and I wanted it to return something if the remainder was apparently here not equal to 0 but I was able to fix.